# "Video Filter missing" in Adobe Premiere

Tags: after-effects, premiere, filter

Adobe Premiere 5.5
OSX

- I have a project I've been working on for a while, which has become **huge**
- It has some Adobe After Effects embedded segments in it, as "Dynamic Links."
- At some point I had a filter in one of the segments (QuickLooksLimited)
- Later on, I changed machines… and didn't reinstall QuickLooksLimited (I think)?
- I've removed some of the AE clips which used this filter, but there may be more

When the project opens, I see the popup message :

> ---
>
> /Volumes/PATH_DIR/PROJECT_NAME.prproj
>
> Video Filter missing:  AE.MB QuickLooksLimited
>
> ---

(the PATH_DIR and PROJECT_NAME are additions for this post)

So my question(s) are:

- how do I find the clip where this darn filter is?
- how do I figure out if the filter is still installed somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

There's one way I know of to find the clip that is using the filter. Inside the timeline, you will see a small badge with the letters 'fx' on your clips. If it it grayed out, there is no effect applied. If it is colored purple, yellow, green, or red, then you have an effect on the clip. You can read about that more here...
http://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/applying-removing-finding-organizing-effects.html

You can find the plugin file in your After Effects folder.

- Windows - Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects\Plug-ins
- Mac - Applications/Adobe After Effects/Plug-ins

Comment: That is a good start with the plugins directory, thanks!

Unfortunately this is an fx-heavy project and every single clip has fx applied.